# Ubuntu 16.04 Cron to run Docker container

Tags: azure, docker, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04 that I want to run cron-scheduled Docker containers on. I have configured the Docker host and my image repository such that they are accessible by the VM, and images run fine on the machine.

My issue is that when I create a cron-schedule using crontab -e in `/var/spool/cron`, the containers do not show up. I should be able to view any stopped containers using `$ docker ps -a`, but it does not show them. Running `sudo grep CRON -i /var/log/syslog` shows the output:

```
Mar 20 16:22:01 SpacyVM CRON[121879]: (bdsadmin) CMD (docker run -d 
bdsdev.azurecr.io/crawler-public)
Mar 20 16:22:05 SpacyVM CRON[121878]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, 
discarding output)
Mar 20 16:24:01 SpacyVM CRON[124254]: (bdsadmin) CMD (docker run -d 
bdsdev.azurecr.io/crawler-public)
Mar 20 16:24:02 SpacyVM CRON[124253]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, 
discarding output)
```

Now, this does run every 2 minutes, per the schedule for debugging purposes, but `docker ps -a` shows nothing, even though the containers should have exited and thus should be idle until I use `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`. Has anyone seen this problem before?

Here is my job configured in crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * docker run -d bdsdev.azurecr.io/crawler-public
```

Note: I have not created a mailing setup for the cronjobs to output to, hence the `No MTA...` error, and I am running this in an Ubuntu VM, not on an Ubuntu docker base image.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem. When I was originally troubleshooting using grep, my search was omitting a fairly important piece of the log stream. So by using vim to view `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar 20 06:34:01 SpacyVM dockerd[1469]: time="2018-03-20T06:34:01.634861659Z" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"
```

I had made a spelling error in my crontab file, so the image is not able to be located by the docker daemon, causing this problem.

Chalk it up to amateur hour